# How to drop large messages with logstash?

Tags: logstash

We're using logstash to capture log messages.

Application logs sometimes contain very long lines and Splunk cannot ingest messages longer than 10k or so (default).

How to drop large messages with logstash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requires Logstash >= 5:

```
filter {
    if [message] {
        ruby {
            code => "event.cancel if event.get('message').bytesize > 8192"
        }
    }
}
```